# What am I doing wrong with Kotlin Spinner to prevent it from working as expected?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have read a number of questions where people are asking this question, and the accepted answer in each case seems to be pretty much what I have here. However, for me, it doesn't seem to be working as I expect. Perhaps I have misunderstood what it should do, but I'm thinking of a spinner  as being akin to a combobox.

I followed a tutorial from stackoverflow that gave me the code below. This all sits in the onCreate. LoadSupplierList is the function that builds my array of values to select from and this is working fine. The values are returned from my api call and loadSupplierList populates the spinner.

```
    val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages) //from strings (direct from the example code I used)
    var list_of_items = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3") //from another example using a built array
    val suppliersAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@AddNewSupplier,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, aSups) //mine

    loadSupplierList()

    spinSelectSupplier.adapter = suppliersAdapter

    spinSelectSupplier?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            selectSupplier(position)
        }

    }
```

selectSupplier is supposed to take the selected item, by position, and populate a textview with the value from the original array.

```
private fun selectSupplier(idx: Int) {
Log.d("spinSelect", aSups[idx])
txtSupplierName.text = aSups[idx]

lblSupplierName.text = getString(R.string.lblSupplierName)
}
```

As far as I can tell, my code is the same as the examples and resolutions provided here, but when I select from the spinner, nothing happens. I don't see an error in logcat and I don't see the Log.d message either. What am I missing?

OK, I've got a little further with this now. I've gone back to basics and copied a example from a site. That worked, both using an array string defined in strings and with a string defined inside the call. Both worked so the problem is clearly my array.

The array is declared inside the class.

```
var aSups: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
var aSupIDs: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

It is populated by a call to loadSupplierList() inside the onCreate:

```
private fun loadSupplierList() {
AllSuppliers.create().getAllSuppliers("all").enqueue(object : Callback<SupplierList> {

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<SupplierList>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("Error :: ", t.localizedMessage!!)
        t.printStackTrace()
    }

    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<SupplierList>,
        response: Response<SupplierList>
    ) {
        Log.d("AllSuppliers :: ", response.body().toString())
        val suppliers = response.body()?.APIResult!![0]

        for (i in 0..suppliers.suppliers.size - 1) {
            Log.d("Each: ", suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)
            Log.d("Each: ", suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_id.toString())
            aSups.add(suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)
            aSupIDs.add(suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_id)
        }                
    }
})
}
```

I can see the Log.d messages appearing in the logcat, so I'm confident that it is being called. Outside the for loop that populates the array I had a log message writing one of the elements to the log, and that was fine. However, the line immediately after the call to loadSupplierList should write the array size:

```
        val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages) //from strings (direct from the example code I used)
        var list_of_items = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3") //from another example using a built array
        val suppliersAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@AddNewSupplier,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, aSups) //mine

        loadSupplierList()

        Log.d("Arr: ", aSups.size.toString())

        if (spinSelectSupplier != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_of_items)
            spinSelectSupplier.adapter = adapter
            spinSelectSupplier.onItemSelectedListener = object :
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                            view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddNewSupplier,
                        "Lang: " + languages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // write code to perform some action
                }
            }
        }
```

This is writing 0 so clearly my array is not being built properly. I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. I'm guessing it's scope related, but if the array is declared in the class, and the loadSuppliersList function is able to access it to write the array, why is onCreate not able to read it immediately afterwards?

Comment: It feels as if your `onItemSelectedListener ` is not being set for some reason, either that spinner is null. Can you try checking that if the `onItemSelected` is being called or not.

Comment: No, it definitely isn't being called. I tried moving the code from the function selectSupplier into the call but still don't see the Log.d being hit

Comment: I feel we need more of the code. Try setting the adapter and onItemSelectedListener before the `loadSupplierList()` function call and just check once that the spinner is not null.

Comment: Nope, no joy. I've changed it to:
spinSelectSupplier?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }

                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    Log.d("spiSelect", aSups[position])
                }

            }

            loadSupplierList()

Comment: Your spinner is null somehow, the code is okay. Nothing wrong with the code. I suggest you check that out